# How can I read a php file into a string using php?

Tags: php

Lets say I want to use a php script to read the current page's code into a string how would I do that without executing the php contents of the page?

For example using

```
file_get_contents("test.php");
```

Will get the contents of test.php but as it does it will execute the code... How can I just get the source code of the file?

Comment: That should work. It won't execute php file.

Comment: Actually, no, `file_get_contents` won't execute the file. Not unless it's on a remote host, in which case what you ask is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` will only execute that file and give you the output as the content if you refer to it as a URL. If you just give a filename, it will attempt to read it from (in your case) the current directory.

Comment: How can I call it? I want to run a html file which calls a php file to read the contents of the first file (html) to get it's source into a string.
I am using:
    file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/".basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
Which is a url right?

Comment: So wait, do you *want* to execute the code of test.php or not?

Comment: I didn't but I was using the full URL instead of the relative location and it was executing the code, I changed it and now it works using a relative path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one way to execute PHP file and get the content into a variable.

You can use the [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)() and [ob_get_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) functions.

```
ob_start();
include "teste.php";
$String = ob_get_clean();
```